# Logging to Oracle Database Table Approach

Tags: database, oracle, db2

We are moving a logging table from DB2 to Oracle, in here we log exceptions and warnings from many applications. With the move I want to accomplish 2 main things among others: less space consumption (to add more rows because tablespaces are kinda small) while not increasing the server processing usage too much (cpu usage increases our bill).

In DB2 we basically have a table that holds text strings.

[image: DB2 table description]

In Oracle I am taking the approach of normalizing the tables for columns with duplicated data (event_type, machine, assemblies, versno). I have a procedure that receives multiple parameters and I query the reference tables to get the IDs.

[image: Oracle Cursor]

This is the Oracle table description.

[image: Oracle Table]

[image: Oracle Table Insert]

One of the feedback I have so far from a co-worker is that I will not necessary reduce table space since indexes take space and my solution might end up using more than what saving all string uses. We don't know if this is true, does anyone have more information on this?

I am taking the right approach?

Will this approach help me accomplish my 2 main goals?

Additional feedback is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: This might be something for the dba exchange. Here, you are asking about opinions.

Comment: It certainly seems doubtful that your aim of reduced tablespace usage will be achieved, but of course it depends - e.g. if the average length of a machine name is 10 characters versus the possible 70 characters, the potential benefit of the numeric key is reduced considerably. The only way to be sure is to create the tables both ways with a reasonable amount of data, and interrogate the database to see how much space the tables and indexes consume.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of using *surrogate keys* (numerical ID) and *dimension tables* (containing the ID key and the description) is popular in both OLPT and data warehouse. IMO the use for logging is a bit strange.

The problem is, the the **logging component should not have much assumption about the data to be logged** - it is vital to be able to log the exeptional cases.

So in case that you can't map the host name to ID (it was misspelled or simple not configured), it would be not much helpfull to log `unknown`host or to suppress the logging at all.

Concerned the storage you can indeed save a lot storing IDs istead of long strings, but (dependent on data) you may get similar effect using table compression.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing about logging is that it works **all the time**. It must be bullet-proof, because if the logger fails you lose the information you need to diagnose problems in your system. Even worse would be to fail business transactions because the logger abended.

There is a strong inverse relationship between the complexity of a logging implementation and its reliability. The more moving parts it has, the more things there are to go wrong. So, while normalization is a good thing for business data it introduces unwelcome risk. Also, look-ups increase the overhead of writing a log message and that is also undesirable.

> " tablespaces are kinda small"

Increasing the chance of failure is not a good trade-off. Ask for more space.